# how to stop animation after using beginAnimations?

Tags: cocoa-touch

i use the following code to do a string rolling, but how to stop the animation?

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"ruucc" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:12.8f];  
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];  
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];  
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];  
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:999999]; 

frame = label1.frame;
frame.origin.x = -12;
label1.frame = frame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554997/cancel-a-uiview-animation

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)doAnimation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:12.8f
                          delay: 0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         frame = label1.frame;
                         frame.origin.x = -12;
                         label1.frame = frame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if(keepAnimating) {
                             [self doAnimation];
                         }
                     }]; 
}
```

In header:

```
BOOL keepAnimating;
```

To start animation:

```
keepAnimating = YES;
[self doAnimation];
```

To stop animation:

```
keepAnimating = NO;
```

This solution uses the block-based animation methods on UIView. Concerning the old set of animation methods ( [UIView beginAnimations] etc ) the UIView class reference states:

Use of the methods in this section is discouraged in iOS 4 and later. Use the block-based animation methods instead.