# cancel UIView Animation

Tags: ios

I use below code for shake button How can i cancel it when it's in progress?

```
#define RADIANS(degrees) ((degrees * M_PI) / 180.0)

    CGAffineTransform leftWobble = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(-10.0));
    CGAffineTransform rightWobble = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(10.0));

    btn.transform = leftWobble;  // starting point

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"wobble" context:btn];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES]; // important
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:20];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(wobbleEnded:finished:context:)];

    btn.transform = rightWobble; // end here & auto-reverse
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I believe that the best way in 2018 would be to use UIViewPropertyAnimator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`CALayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)'s `removeAllAnimations` method:

```
[btn.layer removeAllAnimations];
```