# Stop an UIView Animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton, uiviewanimation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cancel a UIView animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554997/cancel-a-uiview-animation)

I have the following animation and i want to stop it when i press a button. Can you please tell me how can i do it? I can't figure it out how. Thanks.

```
-(void)animationLoop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void    *)context 
{
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Move randomly" context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1]; 
// [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:NO];


CGFloat x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.bounds.size.width); 
CGFloat y = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.bounds.size.height); 

CGPoint squarePostion = CGPointMake(x, y); 
strechView.center = squarePostion; 

[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; 
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationLoop:finished:context:)];

[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
[myView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

and be sure to import the Quartz framework as well:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Animations are applied using CoreAnimation in the QuartzCore framework, even the UIView animation methods. Just target the view's layer that you want to stop animating, and remove its animations.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
[self.view.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"Move randomly"];
```

This is more effective than calling `[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations]` because this can potentially remove other animations that you would want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the object/property that currently animated. It will stop animation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use NSTimer.

```
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(yourAnimation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)responseToButton:(UIButton *) _button {
    //when you want to stop the animation
    [myTimer invalidate];
}

- (void)yourAnimation {
      // move the view to a random point
}
```

Besides, you can set the NSTimer works on another thread so that the main thread can response when you press even your TimeInterval value is very small