# How to interrupt UIView animation before completion?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I am using [UIView animateWithDuration... ] in order to display a text for each page of my app. Each page got its own text. I'm swiping to navigate between pages. I am using a 1 second dissolve effect to have the text fading in after the page is displayed.

Here's the problem: If I'm swiping during that 1 second (during which the text is fading in) the animation will complete when the next page appears and 2 texts will overlap (the previous and the current).

The solution I'd like to implement is to interrupt the animation if I happen to swipe during its occurrence. I just cannot make it happen. [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations]; does not work for me.

Here's my animation code:

```
   - (void) replaceContent: (UITextView *) theCurrentContent withContent: (UITextView *) theReplacementContent {

    theReplacementContent.alpha = 0.0;
    [self.view addSubview: theReplacementContent];


    theReplacementContent.alpha = 0.0;

    [UITextView animateWithDuration: 1.0
                              delay: 0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                         animations: ^{
                             theCurrentContent.alpha = 0.0;
                             theReplacementContent.alpha = 1.0;
                         }
                         completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                             [theCurrentContent removeFromSuperview];
                             self.currentContent = theReplacementContent;
                             [self.view bringSubviewToFront:theReplacementContent];
                         }];

   }
```

Do you guys know how to make this work? Do you know any other way to address this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancel a UIView animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554997/cancel-a-uiview-animation)

Comment: Did you try sending `removeAllAnimations` to `theCurrentContent.layer` and `theReplacementContent.layer`?

Comment: @matt, it's a little bit different though

Answer (score 11):

You can not directly cancel animations created via `+animateWithDuration...`. What you want to do is **replace** the running animation with an instant new one.

You could write the following method, that get's called when you want to show the next page:

```
- (void)showNextPage
{
    //skip the running animation, if the animation is already finished, it does nothing
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.0
                          delay: 0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations: ^{
                         theCurrentContent.alpha = 1.0;
                         theReplacementContent.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                         theReplacementContent = ... // set the view for you next page
                         [self replaceContent:theCurrentContent withContent:theReplacementContent];
                     }];
}
```

Notice the additional `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` passed to `options:`. What this does is, it basically tells the framework to intercept any running animations for the affected properties and replace them with this one. 
By setting the `duration:` to **0.0** the new values are set instantly.

In the `completion:` block you can then create and set your new content and call your `replaceContent:withContent:` method.

Comment: Still working on it. It does not quite fix the issue yet but I suspect I might be doing something wrong adapting your code to mine.

Answer (score 2):

So, another possible solution would be to just disable interaction during the animation.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would declare a flag like `shouldAllowContentToBeReplaced`. Set it to false when the animation starts and back true when it's complete. Then say `if (shouldAllowContentToBeReplaced) {` before you start the animation.