# How to Interrupt UIView Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I've tried following the advice on a couple of other threads, but their approaches do not seem to work in this instance. Here is my situation:

I have 2 scroll views. "Scroll view A" has a label that fades in and out when scrolling "Scroll View A". When "Scroll View B" is dragged I want to immediately hide the label on "Scroll View A". However I cannot interrupt the label's slow fade out animation. 
Here are the two methods I'm using:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

if (scrollView.tag != 1)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{

        self.liveOverlayLabel.alpha = .6;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}

else
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{

        self.liveOverlayLabel.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.liveOverlayLabel.alpha = 0;
    }];
}
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{

if (scrollView.tag != 1)
{

        NSLog(@"stoppping");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

        self.liveOverlayLabel.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}
else
{
    self.liveOverlayLabel.alpha = 0;

}

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancel a UIView animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554997/cancel-a-uiview-animation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UIView animation ends up using CAAnimation objects on the view's layers "under the covers."

To stop an "in-flight" animation, you can use code like this:

#### Objective-C:

```
[aView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

#### Swift:

```
aView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

I believe that for UIView animations, the view will jump to it's end state when the animation is removed.

The other poster's approach of using a new animation with the UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState option would let you add a new animation that began animating a new change to the view using the animation state at the instant the new animation begins as a starting point.

So if you are animating a view from the bottom left to the bottom right of the screen, and halfway through the animation you issue a new UIView animation that moves the view to the **top** right, using the UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState option, the view will change directions, starting at the halfway point, and begin moving to the upper-right corner.

Comment: thanks, [self.liveOverlayLabel.layer removeAllAnimations] did it for me.

Comment: in my case the animation is interrupted by a presented imagePicker. I have to restart the animation. Do you find the solution of reason?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the running view animation could not be interrupted by calling

> removeAllAnimations

on the view layer.

According to this post though:

[How to interrupt UIView animation before completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693795/how-to-interrupt-uiview-animation-before-completion)

there is another way. You could call:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 0, options: .beginFromCurrentState, 
    animations: {
       // perhaps a "closing" animation
    }, 
    completion: { _ in
      // reset specific view state
    })
```

The beginFromCurrentState option intercepts currently running animations and replaces them with the one mentioned in the animations block. If duration is 0 this happens instantly.