# in ios dev, how to handle case based animations?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation

My questions is probably best asked by stating my problem:

In my app, there are two button choices, lets say 1 & 2. when you click and hold on 1, 2 fades out (alpha change) over .3 seconds, and vice versa.

If the user 'cancel's' that button touch (by dragging his finger away from the button and releasing) the opposite button fades back in.

This all works great. The problem arises when the user does not hold down on the button, and clicks it so a touch is registered in under .3 seconds (the time it takes for the other button to fade out) The thing is there are more animations that have to happen after all this so i guess my issue is that animations further down the line interrupt that .3 sec fade and things start to look awkward.

Suggestions to work with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/841967/793607), you should create a secondary UIView animation that goes to the same animation endpoint as your 0.3 second one.  Make sure you set the animation to begin from the current state, and give it as short as time as it will let you.  Basically this will get your views to all look like they would at the end of that first animation, and it will happen much more quickly.  After that animation is done, you would do your other animations based on the button results.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.03];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
// here you set your view and animation stuff from the other animation that takes 0.3 seconds

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This will get you quickly to the state you would be in after the 0.3 second animation and you can begin the animation from there.

Comment: ah perfect looks like `setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState` was the keyword here. thank you!