# iOS stop animateWithDuration before completion

Tags: ios, swift, animatewithduration, ios-animations

I have a CollectionView and I want to create an animation inside the CollectionViewCell selected by the user. I chose to use animateKeyframesWithDuration because I want to create a custom animation step by step. My code looks like this:

```
func animate() {
    UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .AllowUserInteraction, animations: { () -> Void in
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            //  First step
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            //  Second step
        })
        }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
            if self.shouldStopAnimating {
                self.loadingView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
            } else {
                self.animate()
            }
        }
}
```

This is executed inside the custom CollectionViewCell when it is selected.
The problem is that I want to force stop the animation immediately at some certain point. But when I do that, the animation doesn't fully stop, it just moves the remaining animation on a different cell (probably the last reused cell?)

I can't understand why this is happening. I have tried different approaches but none of them successfully stop the animation before normally entering the completion block

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the animations from the layer you could try adding another animation with a very short duration that sets the view properties that you want to stop animating.

Something like this:

```
if self.shouldStopAnimating {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.01, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.beginFromCurrentState, animations: { () -> Void in
        //set any relevant properties on self.loadingView or anything else you're animating
        //you can either set them to the final animation values
        //or set them as they currently are to cancel the animation
    }) { (completed) -> Void in
    }
}
```

[This answer may also be helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554997/cancel-a-uiview-animation)

Comment: It still doesn't work. On my selected cell the animation stops as normal. The real problem is that it continues on another cell. I have also tried with UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false) but in vain. This is really annoying