# Can I stop immediately first UIView animation and start second animation on same view?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I have a question about UIView animation.
I made two animation.
One is changing an alpha value of a view from 0.0 to 1.0.
Another is changing an alpha value of a view from 1.0 to 0.0.

However, user can use second animation before first animation finish.
At that time, second animation doesn't work. (First animation is just in progress until end)

Can I stop first animation and start second animation if second animation function call before first end?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I found the solution. Using UIViewPropertyAnimator is good choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try something like this:

```
myView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2475482/4326715