# Stop function in swift (it is calling animate)

Tags: swift, uikit

in my view controller i have 2 functions, each should stop the animation of the other

```
func firstFunc() {
//i need stop secondFunc here
Alert.show()
//here is starting animate first
    }
```

```
func secondFunc() {
//i need to stop firstFunc here
        Alert.show()
//here is starting animate second
    }
```

In my UI i have 2 buttons for this functions that starting long animate

Comment: How do you "animate"? Are you animating the same element? You tagged with `jquery-animate`? Aren't you using `UIView.animate`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47208599/1801544 ?

Comment: i have a lot of things in first and second functions. And inside of it i have class that has animation inside of it. I just need to stop performance of function if i tap on other function. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, i use UIView.animate

Comment: when i write "animate" tag its changing on jquery-animate

Comment: See the linked question. You can cancel the animations...